# Adding permission to specific section Kentico

Tags: kentico

Am using **Kentico 9** in creating book store that will contain more than one section like Fiction Books and so on .. i want to assign rule to user that allow him to manage this section only to add/modify/delete books, and so on with the rest of the sections .. i can now assign manager or editor that can modify all products, but i need to make him belongs to just one category of products .. also i've tried to assign department to products and just assign user to manage it but still it doesn't make sense .. i've tried to check [Kentico Doc](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Role+management) to find an answer on this question but i didn't find the solution, can any one help me in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the **Default alias path** property within the user configuration (**Users -> user -> General -> Default alias path**) where you can specify what section of the content tree your user will see. Then you can just set proper permissions.

Comment: Just FYI from docs:
"Note: This feature (Starting alias path) is only intended for better usability and does not ensure security control. If you need to establish access rights for a given user, grant appropriate page permissions on the Properties -> Security tab." 
So I strongly do not recommned this approach and IMHO this is not best practice.
[source](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/User+management)

Answer (score 1):

Does your category (or section) of products have the same page type? If so you can set proper permissions for CRUD operations (and more) per each page type (type of product). Just go to **Permission** > **Permissions for: Page type** and set proper rights.You can learn more [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Permissions+for+page+types).

If not, you can still use Page-level permissions - [ACLs](https://docs.kentico.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59638426) (just follow example section).